# Skip Email Verifications On Adding O365 Guest User

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We would like to skip the email verification step in the process of adding a guest user in an O365 tenant. There is an [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that allows one to create an invitation through which we can disable 'email notification' but if the newly added user does not have an account on any of the O365 tenants then email verification seems to be mandatory.

Our application uses microsoft graph apis along with custom UI's for integrating with microsoft teams. For our application, email verification needs to be skipped since the user is already authenticated and authorized before he reaches the microsoft teams UI.

Is there anyway through which the email verification could be skipped?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andy Dufresne:

Firstly, we can't skip the email verification process, it's a mandatory.
For your requirement, could you please have a look on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/add-guests).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I read the document and it seems indeed we cannot skip email verification. Even if the guest user is added directly to the team by the admin, he still gets the verification email if he is not part of any O365 tenant.